# getQueryParams() from gridview's url after search and create another URL with same params for anchor tag inside GridView

Tags: php, yii, yii2, pjax

I'm using `GridView::widget`, when I enter anything on search box inside gridview, it's creating url as below:

```
/v2/backend/web/index.php/agency/index?AgencySearch%5Bgovt_name%5D=&AgencySearch%5Bcity%5D=&AgencySearch%5Bmember_id%5D=22
```

Now I need to pass those paramters to url inside status icons present under GridView's Status column.

```
echo Url::to(['agency/change-status', 'id' => 33, 'set' => 11, Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams()]);
```

Above code is creating url as below:

```
/v2/backend/web/index.php/agency/33/change-status/11?1%5BAgencySearch%5D%5Bgovt_name%5D=&1%5BAgencySearch%5D%5Bcity%5D=&1%5BAgencySearch%5D%5Bmember_id%5D=22
```

And it makes sense because `Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams()` is an array. Note `1` inside url `change-status/11?1%5BAgencySearch`

Is there any simplest Yii way of achieving what I need instead of modifying `Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams()` as per `Url::to()` that is into string.

I'm trying to pass parameters in order to persist the state of gridview while loading contents again on grid after status change pjax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to combine your route and parameters and the search params.

```
$params = array_merge(['agency/change-status', 'id' => 33, 'set' => 11], Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
echo Url::to($params);
```

Comment: Perfect, it makes more sense to array_merge that way, I was just thinking about merging params and missed the URL part directly.